# Как вызвать функцию при клике по ссылке

Tags: jquery

Есть ссылки

```html
<a href="#tab1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#tab2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#tab3">Link 3</a>
```

Мне нужно вызвать разные функции, в зависимости на какую ссылку кликнули, так как подставить ссылкам id нет возможности, нужно определять ссылку по *href*

Как это реализовать?

Comment: @test123 дело в том что нет возможности изменить ссылку, или добавить к ней атрибуты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте селектор с указанным значением атрибута, например `a[href="#tab1"]`

```js
$("a[href='#tab1']").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('tab1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#tab1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#tab2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#tab3">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: **a[href='#tab1']** - то что нужно было! спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tab1Fn = () => console.log('tab1');
const tab2Fn = () => console.log('tab2');
const tab3Fn = () => console.log('tab3');
document.querySelectorAll('a')
  .forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  let id = ev.target.getAttribute('href').slice(1);
  switch (id) {
    case 'tab1': tab1Fn(); break;
    case 'tab2': tab2Fn(); break;
    case 'tab3': tab3Fn(); break;
    default: return;
  }
  ev.preventDefault();
}));
```

```html
<a href="#tab1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#tab2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#tab3">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: `a[href^="#tab"]` может тогда, чтобы не на всю страницу вешать?

Comment: и не навешивать общий обработчик, в возвращать функцию-обработчик? типа там `case 'tab1'`: return tab1Fn;`